# application_record model is generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From the Rails 5.2 release notes:

```
ApplicationRecord is no longer generated when generating models. If you need to generate it, it can be created with rails g application_record. (Pull Request)
```

I generated a new app, using the Syntax:

```
rails new TestApp -d mysql
```

But the an application_record.rb file was created in app/models

```
rails -v
```

produces:

```
Rails 5.2.2

ruby -v
```

produces:

```
ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

I am on a Mac Mojave.

Is it a bug, or did I misunderstand the release notes?

Comment: Apparently, the docs state that `ApplicationRecord` is no longer generated *when generating models*. It appears from your question that `ApplicationRecord` was generated *when creating the app*, no? If so, then everything seems consistent, yes?

Comment: But isn't models generation part of a new app creation?

Comment: Welp. When you generate a `new` app (but have not yet done `rails g model ...`), other than `ApplicationRecord`, what models do you see in the models directory?

Comment: Ah, OK, I see what you're saying. I don't have any models yet, but I was confused because the models directory was created and application_record was in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you've misunderstood the release notes.

When you create a new app, the `models` directory is created and `ApplicationRecord` is created in the `models` directory. But, you see, you haven't generated any models yet. That will happen when you do `rails g model ...`.

When you (eventually) do `rails g model ...`, then (as stated in the release notes), `ApplicationRecord` will not be generated because it was already generated when you created the app.